# CS50 PSET6: Parse function doesn't change pointers content

Tags: c, function, pointers, cs50

In one of my assignements I'm asked to implement a function which main role in the take a line of an HTTP request and extract from it multiple subtrings(Method, HTTP version etc).Please consider that the error function is already implemented.
Here is the function:

```
    bool parse(const char* line, char* abs_path, char* query)
{
    //I don't wanna deal with a const :p so I copied it into a normal string.
    char *token;
    char _line[strlen(line)];
    strcpy(_line, line);

    //Dividing the line into a Method, a request target, and a HTTP_version
    char *search = " ";
    token = strtok(_line, search);
    char method[strlen(token)];
    strcpy(method, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, search);
    char request_target[strlen(token)];
    strcpy(request_target, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, search);
    char HTTP[strlen(token)];
    strcpy(HTTP, token);

    //Some error Handling
    if (strcasecmp(method, "GET")!=0)
    {
       error(405);
       return false;
    }
    if(request_target[0]!='/')
    {
       error(501);
       return false;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(request_target); i++)
    {
       if(request_target[i]=='"')
       {
          error(400);
          return false;
       }
    }
    if (strcasecmp(HTTP, "HTTP/1.1")!=0)
    {
       error(505);
       return false;
    }


    char *search2 = "?";
    char* temp1 = strtok(request_target, search2);
    abs_path = malloc(strlen(temp1)+1);
    strcpy(abs_path, temp1);
    char* temp2 = strtok(NULL, search2);
    query = malloc(strlen(temp2)+1);
    strcpy(query, temp2);
    return true;
   }
```

So the problem with this function is that it doesn't affect the content of the two pointers: abs_path and query. After debugging it I realised that inside the function the two of them get their correct values, but it's another story in the main function.

Could you please help me ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `char _line[strlen(line)];` --> `char _line[strlen(line)+1];` : +1 for null-terminator. ditto.

Comment: pass pointers by pointer or they won't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current function signature:

```
bool parse(const char* line, char* abs_path, char* query)
```

`abs_path` and `query` are passed by value. Changing them in the procedure has a local effect only (they are auto variables)

you have to change method params so pointers can be changed (I changed the parameter names too):

```
bool parse(const char* line, char** pabs_path, char** pquery)
```

then in the code

```
*pabs_path = malloc(strlen(temp1)+1);
strcpy(*pabs_path, temp1);
char* temp2 = strtok(NULL, search2);
*pquery = malloc(strlen(temp2)+1);
strcpy(*pquery, temp2);
```

When calling procedure:

```
const char* line = "some string";
char* abs_path,* query;
r = parse(line, &abs_path, &query);
```

and the comment of BLUEPIXY is valid: allocate 1 char more or you get an out of bounds

```
 char _line[strlen(line)+1]
```

this error is repeated throughout your code: look for `[strlen(` in your code, you'll see that you often forget to add 1 for the null terminator.

Comment: Mercii :) I apreciate it